# ¿Como mostrar los datos de un struct?

Tags: c, estructuras-de-datos, imprimir

He hecho este programa para guardar la informacion sobre un libro pero no imprime los datos correctamente.

En principio los debe guardar bien, porque si pongo los `printf`dentro de la funcion donde se guardan los datos, si que se imprimen correctamente. Pero al modularizar el programa, deja de hacerlo.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Color {rojo, verde, azul};

struct Libro{
    int paginas;
    char* autor;
    char* titulo;
    enum Color color;
};

void datosLibro(struct Libro libro){
    libro.paginas = 200;
    libro.autor = "Cervantes";
    libro.titulo = "El Quijote";
    libro.color = verde;

}

void mostrarDatos(struct Libro libro){

    printf("paginas: %d\n", libro.paginas);
    printf("autor: %s\n", libro.autor);
    printf("titulo: %s\n", libro.titulo);

    switch (libro.color) {
        case rojo:
            printf("Color: rojo\n");
            break;
        case verde:
            printf("Color: verde\n");
            break;
        case azul:
            printf("Color: azul\n");
            break;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Libro libro1;

    datosLibro(libro1);
    mostrarDatos(libro1);

    return 0;
}
```

¿Alguien sabe donde esta el fallo?

Answer (score 1):

El problema es porque el resultado de la llamada a `datosLibro(libro1);` no los está recibiendo ninguna variable local en `main()`, al contrario, le estás mandando una referencia vacía (`libro1`) a esa función.

Para solucionarlo, cambiar la función de carga de datos para que retorne la estructura:

```
struct Libro datosLibro(){
    struct Libro libro;
    libro.paginas = 200;
    libro.autor = "Cervantes";
    libro.titulo = "El Quijote";
    libro.color = verde;
    return libro;
}
```

y la función main()

```
int main(){
    struct Libro libro1;

    libro1 = datosLibro();
    mostrarDatos(libro1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que en C, al llamar a una [funcion con parametros](http://www.it.uc3m.es/pbasanta/asng/course_notes/functions_passing_parameters_es.html), la funcion recibe una copia de los datos, por lo que al llenar tu estructura, lo que haces es llenar una copia local que se destruye cuando la funcion termina, para guardar los datos en tu estructura, manda un puntero como parametro, de esa forma tu funcion recibe una copia de la direccion donde tiene que escribir.

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum Color {rojo, verde, azul};

struct Libro{
    int paginas;
    char* autor;
    char* titulo;
    enum Color color;
};

void datosLibro(struct Libro *libro){
    libro->paginas = 200;
    libro->autor = "Cervantes";
    libro->titulo = "El Quijote";
    libro->color = verde;

}

void mostrarDatos(struct Libro libro){

    printf("paginas: %d\n", libro.paginas);
    printf("autor: %s\n", libro.autor);
    printf("titulo: %s\n", libro.titulo);

    switch (libro.color) {
        case rojo:
            printf("Color: rojo\n");
            break;
        case verde:
            printf("Color: verde\n");
            break;
        case azul:
            printf("Color: azul\n");
            break;
    }
}

int main(){
    struct Libro libro1;

    datosLibro(&libro1);
    mostrarDatos(libro1);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realice esta modificación en la acción datosLibros:

```
    void datosLibro(struct Libro  * libro){
    libro->paginas = 200;
    libro->autor = "Cervantes";
    libro->titulo = "El Quijote";
    libro->color = verde;
    }
```

Ten en cuenta que cuando modificas un libro en la acción, debes pasar la dirección de memoria del libro1, no una copia. Ya que cuando modifiques los valores en la acción nunca se van a ver reflejados en libro1 sino en la dirección de memoria del parámetro(libro). Por ello, cuando querías ver su información te mostraba basura.
(Y cuando dices que, cuando  mostrabas los datos desde la acción funcionaba, es por que estabas mostrando los datos guardados en la dirección de memoria del parámetro libro, no los de libro1).

Espero te sirva de ayuda!